# How to get the right s3 keys?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I have an S3 bucket with thousands of keys in tested directories:
Iterating through each key with:

```
for key in bucket.list():
  print key.name
```

Yields output like:

"/dir2/dir2/banana/dir4/file1"
"/dir1/dir2/apple/dir4/file2"

The problem is when I iterate like this, it is very slow if all I want is a list of all the keys that have "/dir1/dir2/apple". Also, if there are no keys that match this criteria it is very slow as it appears to iterate over all keys.

What is the correct way to get a listing of the keys within the buckets that I want?

Answer (score 2):

Look up the `delimiter` and `prefix` parameters in the [docs](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.get_all_keys)

```
for files in bucket.get_all_keys(delimiter = '/', prefix = '/dir1/dir2/'):
    print files
```

While `delimiter` will always be `/` , `prefix` can be set to anything you like depending on the location you want to read files from

Comment: You may get away with a leading `/` in the prefix (iirc, s3 is somewhat permissive here), but technically, unlike a filesystem, s3 keys at the root of the bucket don't actually begin with `/`.  Since it's a "prefix" there is no need to anchor it to the left side.  The trailing slash, however, is definitely correct, and often overlooked. +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

conn = S3Connection()  # assumes your .boto is populated with keys

bucket = conn.get_bucket('bucketname')

theobjects = [key.name for key in bucket.get_all_keys() if     key.name.startswith('dir1/dir2/apple')]

print theobjects  # should return just the names in a list (unicode)
```

of course this assumes it's the initial prefix, if you want to search for a contains a string, you'll need to upgrade to regular expression (not sure if str.find will work for you)

```
import re
theobjects = [key.name for key in bucket.get_all_keys() if re.search('/dir1/dir2/apple', key.name)]
```